# Creating AJAX call with foreach data values

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I basically have a list of 'form data' which each contain an attribute.
Each attribute has their own separate data such as ID, QuestionText etc.

Below I have my HTML with my data binds for pageitems and then I am setting the 'attributeid' as the id for the table, which all works fine.

What i want to do now is where it says '$root.getAttributeTitle()', I need to make an ajax call to retrieve the attribute data for the 'attributeid' that was mentioned above, but whenever I make a function for example,

```
self.getAttributeTitle = function(id){
   var sTitle = '';
   $.post(url, sendData, function(response){
       sTitle = response.data.QuestionTitle;
   });
   return sTitle;
}
```

...it tries to return the value before the ajax call is even complete.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

```
<!--ko foreach: pageitems-->
<table class="table" data-bind="attr: { id: $data.attributeid() }">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" data-bind="text: $root.getAttributeTitle($data.attributeid())"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: that's how ko works . have you tried keeping return in `.complete()` i'm not sure it gonna help you . can you get all the list of titles with ids & store in a array and query it (avoid ajax call).

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bind to a data-fetching function call, bind to an `observable` that is a member of `pageitems`, and do your async data fetch when you populate `pageitems`. Knockout will fill in the titles as it gets them.

You'll need to modify the fetch routine to populate the observable, which works neatly:

```
self.getAttributeTitle = function(id, observable){
   $.post(url, sendData, observable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should delay your code until the Ajax call is complete, you can't expect your code to return a value from a remote location right away. here is how you can change the usage of your getAttributeTitle function:

```
getAttributeTitle (id) {
   var _this = this;
   return $.post(url, sendData);
}

//then you can use it like this:
getAttributeTitle(id).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data.QuestionTitle);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using $.post which is a shorthand for $.ajax and it does not have option to set asynchronous. Bu default $.post will consider async = true which is causing to run to next line without waiting for the response.
You have to put

```
$.ajaxSetup({ asynch: false })
```

before your $.post and then at the end again enable

```
$.ajaxSetup({ asynch: true }).
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but I had already considered using async: false for the $.post call, but was hoping for an answer using knockout models or examples where someone overcame this without using synchronous Ajax calls.